# Z3py: Array of specific integer type?

Tags: python, z3

In Z3Python, I want to declare an array of bytes (meaning each member of array is of integer of 8 bits). I tried with the following code, but apparently it reports that Int(8) is illegal type.

Any idea on how to fix the problem? Thanks!

```
I = IntSort()
I8 = Int(8)
A = Array('A', I, I8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot provide a number as argument of the Int() function. It expects a string (the name of the integer actually) and not the size, in bits, of the integer. You might want to consider using bit vectors instead:

```
Byte = BitVecSort(8)
i8 = BitVec('i8', Byte)
A = Array('A', IntSort(), Byte)
```